# Преобразовать текст в нижний регистр, в случае, если в нем слишком много заглавных

Tags: php

Надо взять из переменной некий произвольный текст, написанный и большими и малыми буквами в неизвестном процентном соотношении, и если количество букв верхнего регистра в тексте составляет некоторые X процентов (задаваемый вручную параметр), то весь текст переводится в нижний регистр.
Необходимо это для отлова любителей СТРОЧИТЬ ОБЪЯВЛЕНИЯ КАПСЛОКОМ. Проверка процентного соотношения делается для тех добросовестных пользователей, кто позволяет себе иногда выделить по смыслу несколько слов капсом.

Хотелось бы оформить в виде функции.

Comment: ну может хоть для приличия сами попробуете?

Comment: Задачка любопытная... Если алгоритмом: 1. убираете из текста все, кроме букв; 2. считаете кол-во заглавных; 3. считаете процент заглавных от общего текста; 4. наказываете виновных, меняя регистар.... Регулярные выражения тут незаменимы. Я бы сделал так. А как Вы пытались?

Comment: Переводим текст в нижний регистр, сравниваем с оригиналом через алгоритм Левинштейна, смотрим количество различающихся символов, делим на длину строки - вот он процент. Мы не ищем легких путей)

Comment: Задача действительно оказалась довольно интересной, по моему ей самое место на ruSO.

Comment: @Mike, задача, увы, и разряда "_сделайте за меня_".

Comment: @DmitriySimushev В общем да, но это не мешает ей быть не страндартной, быстро не гуглящейся. Обратите внимание, в правилах ничего не сказано по поводу "работа за автора"

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Код поддерживающий кодировку UTF-8 и русские символы. Считает длину *только букв*, пробелы, знаки препинания и прочие символы не учитываются. Вы можете взять полную длину строки `mb_strlen($text)` вычесть из нее `$txtL` и `$txtU` и получить эти самые не буквенные символы и так же посчитать их соотношение, возможно это то же может пригодится ...

```
<?php
$text="Необходимо это для отлова любителей СТРОЧИТЬ ОБЪЯВЛЕНИЯ КАПСЛОКОМ. Проверка процентного соотношения делается ";
$text=magicLower($text);
print $text;

function magicLower($text)
{
 $txtL=mb_strlen(preg_replace("/[^а-яёa-z]+/u","",$text));
 $txtU=mb_strlen(preg_replace("/[^А-ЯЁA-Z]+/u","",$text));
 if(!$txtL) $txtL=0.01;
 print "LowerCase: $txtL,  Upper case: $txtU  rate:".($txtU/$txtL)."\n";
 if($txtU/$txtL<0.1) return $text;
 return preg_replace_callback("/(?<=[A-ZА-ЯЁ])([A-ZА-ЯЁ\s]+)/u",
          function($match) { return mb_convert_case($match[0], MB_CASE_LOWER, "UTF-8"); },$text);
}
?>
```

Функция magicLower переводит в нижний регистр только не одиночные большие буквы, возможно разделяемые пробелом. Таким образом красота нормальных предложений сохраняется, они остаются с больших букв. Результат работы данного кода:

```
LowerCase: 134,  Upper case: 58  rate:0.43283582089552
Необходимо это для отлова любителей Строчить объявления капслоком. Проверка процентного соотношения делается
```

Comment: Ваш код не работает для строки `АБВ` и не правильно работает для строки `Ёж под Ёлкой`.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Спасибо, поправил